# Printform in c# 2008

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008

How to use the powerpack PrintForm? i want to print the winform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First use the name space

```
using Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks.Printing;
```

Suppose you have two forms say Form1 and Form2. You have a print button in Form1 and on click the button you need to print Form2. Foe this do as

**Form 1**

```
private void printButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      Form2 f = new Form2();
      f.Show();      
}
```

**Form 2**

```
private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      this.Hide();
      printForm1.Print(this, PrintForm.PrintOption.ClientAreaOnly);
      this.Close();
}
```